# How to mention a coding style guide in thesis or scientific text

Tags: writing-style, code

Is there a best practice where or how to introduce a style guide inside a thesis?
(Meant is a style guide for programming languages)

I write a scientific text which contains some code samples. My studies are in a non-coding field, so there is no official style guide provided. I choose to use one provided by [Google](https://developers.google.com/style/code-syntax).

When searching, the results are about style guides for the actual thesis or how to format code in a thesis, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just say "Coding style X is used," at the point where you have the first code sample? If the coding style is very important and relevant to the content of the paper, write a bit more. If it is not relevant at all, don't write anything. I don't think it really matters and I don't think you need to worry about "best practice."